# No data displayed with Firebase Security Rules

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am struggling to secure my Firebase.

I did something like this to secure my user list.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /about/{id} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
match /avantages/{id} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
match /blog/{id} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
match /customers/{id} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
match /lowersection/{id} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
match /middlesection/{id} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
match /topsection/{id} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    
match /users/{userId} {
allow read: if isOwner(userId);
allow write: if isOwner(userId);
}
}
function isOwner(userId) {
return request.auth.uid == userId;
 }
}
```

But once I do this, I have no data displayed on my web site.

The goal is to have the data readable by everyone (except the users collection) but the data only writable by logged-in users.

As requested, below is the code from the Angular App that allows it to get the data and send back the updated data.

```
getTopSectionMain() {
return   this.firestore.collection('topsection').doc('content').collection('main').snaps hotChanges();
}

updateTopSectionMain(dataID: any, data: any) {
this.firestore.doc('topsection/content/main/' + dataID).update(data);
}
```

This is from my content service.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Ah yes, it seems I forget that one but that would only affect logged-in users and not the web site visitors ?

Comment: I actually deleted my comment before you answered :-) I was mentioning that there isn't any rule for `read` for the `users` collection. So none can read docs in this collection.

Comment: Note that with the modification you have just done (`match /users/{userId} {
allow read: if true;`) anyone can read all the docs in the `users` collection.

Comment: I added "allow read: if true;" in the user section. That should do it for what you mentioned. But that still does not work. And I can't find any error with my measly knowledge.

Comment: note my comment above: with this change, your goal ("have the data readable by everyone (except the users collection)") is not reached, since anyone can read all the docs in the `users` collection.

Comment: In order to help you you need to share the code you use to read/write the Firestore documents. Only with this code we can help you. For the moment we can only say that if you test your rules with the "Rules playground" you will confirm that anybody can read docs in any collection.

Comment: Now that you have reverted back to the initial version (you removed `match /users/{userId} { allow read: if true;`) the above comment should read: "For the moment we can only say that if you test your rules with the "Rules playground" you will confirm that anybody can read docs in all the collections unless the `users` one"

Comment: Yeah, I got that ^^ . I will edit with the code from my angular app for edit/write. I also modified the rules so you can't read the user collection unless you are logged-in.

Comment: It seems that you are actually reading documents that are in sub-collections (`firestore.collection('topsection').doc('content').collection('main')`). Can you confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to come from the fact that you read **documents that are in sub-collections**.

Let's take the example of the `topsection` collection. You have a security rule as follows:

```
match /topsection/{id} {
    allow read: if true;
    allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
}
```

but you query documents as follows:

```
getTopSectionMain() {
    return   this.firestore.collection('topsection').doc('content').collection('main').snaps hotChanges();
}
```

which means that you query documents of the `main` subcollection of the `content` doc which is in the `topsection` collection.

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#hierarchical_data): "Security rules apply only at the matched path, so the access controls defined on the (parent) collection do not apply to the (child) subcollection."

You need to adapt your rule by either adding a [recursive wildcard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards)

```
match /topsection/{document=**} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
}
```

or specifying each subcollection like:

```
match /topsection/{id} {
    match /main/{id} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
}
```

Since you didn’t use wildcards  for declaring the security rules for the top collections,  you may preferably use the second option.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used a wildcard (because I was too lazy to write an entry for each subcollection xD ). I get it know how it works :)